# I have pandas dataframe which i would like to be sliced after every 4 columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe which i would like to be sliced after every 4 columns  and then vertically stacked on top of each other which includes the date as index.Is this possible by using np.vstack()? Thanks in advance!

[ORIGINAL DATAFRAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOqll.png)

Please refer the image for the dataframe.
I want something like this

[WANT IT MODIFIED TO THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHxQo.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That means no images, no links, just text containing your data and code. Thank you.

Comment: This is just a slice of the entire dataframe, it has 180 columns in total

Comment: Still, it is not copyable for me so I can't really help. You can paste a snippet or the screenshot content in text alongside your code.

Comment: Agreed with iDrwish

Comment: My apologies guys!

Answer (score 0):

Until you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I will not test this answer but the following should work:

given that we have the data stored in a `Pandas DataFrame` called `df`, we can use `pd.melt`

```
moltendfs = []
for i in range(4):
    moltendfs.append(df.iloc[:, i::4].reset_index().melt(id_vars='date'))
newdf = pd.concat(moltendfs, axis=1)
```

We use `iloc` to take only every fourth column, starting with the i-th column. Then we `reset_index` in order to be able to keep the date column as our identifier variable. We use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) in order to melt our DataFrame. Finally we simply concatenate all of these molten DataFrames together side by side.

Comment: my_list_1=[]
for i in range(4):
     my_list_1.append(securities_df_final.iloc[:,i::4].reset_index().melt(id_vars='Date'))
new_df=pd.concat(my_list_1,axis=1)

Comment: got an error running the above code KeyError: 'Date'
I have got Date as one of the columns

Comment: Again, provide a testable snippet of code, so I can reproduce your problem. Without part of your DataFrame, it will be hard for me to do that

Comment: You may find this answer from a question about how to do that for pandas questions useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32536193/7480990